# Italian Babel and commas in math mode that are typeset as inverted E

Tags: math-mode, babel

The two cryptic lines by EGreg in this minimal example

```
\documentclass{book} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian,british]{babel} 

\usepackage[onlytext]{MinionPro}
\usepackage{minionmath}

\mathchardef\virgola=\mathcode`,
\def\virgoladecimale{{\virgola}}

\begin{document}     
Hallo. $(a,b)$. $(c, d)$.    
\end{document}
```

worked in Texlive 2014. In the new texlive, this again yields an inverted E instead of a comma between a and b, as well as between c and d. Taking the lines out does not work either. What can be done?

Comment: I can't say what happens with `MinionPro` and `minionpromath` for lack of fonts; I've always found the introduction of `\virgola` and `\virgoladecimale` the wrong way to cope with the problem in `italian.ldf`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding one further line of code, with `\AtBegin...` solved the problem:

```
\documentclass{book} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian,british]{babel} 

\usepackage[onlytext]{MinionPro}
\usepackage{minionmath}

\mathchardef\virgola=\mathcode`,
\def\virgoladecimale{{\virgola}}
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`,=\virgola}

\begin{document}     
Hallo. $(a,b)$. $(c, d)$.    
\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).